# Port seems to be closed although Service is listening

Tags: server, firewall, minecraft

I have a Server running Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 LTS and Minecraft on my local network. My problem is that I cannot connect to the server from my local network.

The Server and Minecraft are both started and the MC Server is configured to use the port 25565.

As a router I have a Zywall USG 50.

While the command `netstat -an | grep "LISTEN "` shows that the server is listening on port 25565:
[Netstat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wW6b.png).

a nmap scan performed from the server shows that the port is not open:
[nmap scan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTcVO.png).

I have also checked the firewall configuration and it is set to allow the specified port.

I am at a loss here and would greatly appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: I see from your netstat output that its made a ipv6 socket but it shows a ipv4 listen address 0.0.0.0, this is very strange. Never setup minecraft server, does it have a config to set the listen address?

Comment: There is, but changing it doesn't do anything (tried it). It is mainly for if you have a dedicated public IP address available that you want to bind the server to.

Comment: What is the exact `nmap` command that you ran? what is the result of `grep 25565 /usr/share/nmap/nmap-services`?

Comment: @steeldriver the exact nmap command I ran was `nmap -sT -O localhost`. The result of `grep 25565 /usr/share/nmap/nmap-services` is [Grep Result](http://prntscr.com/dyf2ng)